# $.ajax response generates error in content-Type:application/json for xml content in json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, httphandler

This is very simple.I think i may be having an issue with incompatible response content type

This is the code i am using to send a jQuery ajax request:

```
 var settings = { dataType: 'json',
                url: 'services/loadTemplate.ashx',
                data: JSON.stringify({ 'Name': element.name }), // element.name },
                processData: false,
                //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                console.log('successData:'+data);
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                    alert(err.Message);
                }
            }
            $.ajax(settings);
```

and this is the response i am trying to fetch in `success` callback.

```
{
  'name': 'sMan',
  'svg1': '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="513" height="490"><desc>Created with Raphaël</desc><defs></defs><text x="50.5" y="50" text-anchor="middle" font="10px &quot;Arial&quot;" stroke="none" fill="#000000" font-size="0px" style="text-anchor: middle; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 0px; line-height: normal; font-family: Arial;"><tspan>Text</tspan></text><image x="173.5" y="79.5" width="176" height="158" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="uploaded/75884f70-8872-49c1-8337-2cbbca626b2e.png" id="P28m" fill="#ff0000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" font-family="Calibri" style="stroke-width: 1px; fill-opacity: 1; stroke-opacity: 1; font-family: Calibri;"></image></svg>',
  'svg2': ''
}
```

But success is not fired.I am setting   `context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";` in the server side request handler and am simply writing the above string to response.Whats the correct way to do this?

***EDIT***:

returning it this way:

```
 return "{'name':'" + name + @"',
                'svg1':'" + dt.Rows[0]["svg1"].ToString() + @"',
                'svg2':'" + dt.Rows[0]["svg2"].ToString() + "'}";
```

**This worked:**

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
        using (JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
        {
            jsonWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            //  jsonWriter.WriteStartArray();
            jsonWriter.WriteStartObject();
            jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("name");
            jsonWriter.WriteValue(name);
            jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("svg1");
            jsonWriter.WriteValue(dt.Rows[0]["svg1"].ToString());
            jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("svg2");
            jsonWriter.WriteValue(dt.Rows[0]["svg2"].ToString());
            jsonWriter.WriteEndObject();

           /* return "{'name':'" + name + @"',
                'svg1':'" + dt.Rows[0]["svg1"].ToString() + @"',
                'svg2':'" + dt.Rows[0]["svg2"].ToString() + "'}";*/
        }

        return sb.ToString();
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON, you need to delimit strings using double-quotes, not single-quotes.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist you mean to say `"svg1":"<svg ..."` would work?

Comment: Use a proper JSON encoder instead of building the string yourself, would be the best way. Also personally I don't like the idea of nesting XML in JSON, I'd look at using a pure-XML format

Comment: You'd also need to change `'name': 'sMan',` to `"name": "sMan",`, etc (and don't forget to escape the double-quotes inside the value for `svg1`). But yes, if you actually return a valid JSON string I'd expect it to work.

Comment: @DaveRandom the XML is an SVG graphic, he is passing information and graphics related to that information. I don't see why JSON is a bad fit here. I agree that if the payload was ONLY xml, then using XML would make more sense.

Comment: How are you using ASP.NET? Can I assume an MVC controller?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Think you directed that comment at the wrong person, I didn't say JSON was a bad fit; just that what he's returning isn't actually JSON.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist sorry, my bad, edited.

Comment: @Nezam I would encourage you to strongly type your response object, and use JsonConvert, instead of handcrafting your return json. I rest my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not in your JavaScript code or in your jQuery API usage. Like [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703774/ajax-response-generates-error-in-content-typeapplication-json-for-xml-content/19704440#comment29268758_19703774) have pointed out it is in the server side. More specifically, JSON object keys [have to be double quotes](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) (and more generally JSON strings have to be double quoted).

As you are using C# and ASP.NET from the code you posted. You have alternatives depending on what framework you're using. In All cases, I suggest you use an object instead of building the JSON yourself.

```
var yourObj = new {name=name,svg1=dt.Rows[0]["svg1"].ToString(),svg2=dt.Rows[0]["svg2"].ToString()}
```

Now you have a C# object representing your data.

If you're using something like ASP.NET MVC:

```
return Json(yourObj,JsonBehavior.AllowGet);
```

If you're using **WebAPI** you can just do

```
return yourObj; // will figure out JSON conversion itself
```

If you're using **anything else**, or whatever you're using does not support JSON responses itself. You need to get the [`Newtonsoft.JSON`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) package from NuGet and return:

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObj);
```

Which will convert your object to a string validly.

Comment: thanks i was using C# asp.net 3.4 webforms.Thanks for the WebAPI part although i used Newtonsoft to solve the issue.

any more pointers to WebApi usage samples on JSON would be really good

Comment: @Nezam WebAPI does something called "Content Negotiation". This means you can return normal C# objects from it and it'll figure out what format to return it in based on what the client requests. So, it automatically responds to json requests by JSON serializing the return value, and to xml requests by XML serializing the return value and so on.

Comment: that means asp.net 3.5 should support it by default?

Comment: @Nezam no, it's a part of the WebAPI framework. Internally it uses Newtonsoft.JSON.

Comment: Interesting. I did not know WebAPI used JSON.NET internally. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

You should create a strong typed object for return type and then convert it to JSON.

```
public class Template
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string SvgXml1 {get; set;}
    public string SvgXml2 {get; set;}
}
```

then in your server side .ashx:

```
var template = new Template 
{
    Name = name,
    SvgXml1 = dt.Rows[0]["svg1"].ToString(),
    SvgXml2 = dt.Rows[0]["svg2"].ToString()
};

return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(template);
```

and finally in your success callback function:

```
var name = data.Name;
var svg1 = data.SvgXml1;
...
```

Comment: This answer is wrong in several accords. If we disregard the obvious (the names don't fit, it's JsonConvert not JSONConvert) and the misinformation (you _don't_ need to explicitly declare an actual class for it), given OP's code the $.parseJSON is still not required. Not to mention it does not add _useful_ information on top of my answer from 3 minutes earlier.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum That's your opinion. Strongly typed classes for returning data are sign of good development. It means that the server side method will always conform to a datacontract, and not rely on magic strings. Thanks for informing me about the typo, but you could have edited it instead of downvoting. Talk about an over-inflated ego!

Comment: When you make a jQuery `$.ajax` request like OP did with `dataType: "json"` jQuery will automatically return the _parsed_ object as a result. See `_ajaxConvert` in the jQuery source code

Comment: See? Was that not easy rather than calling someone a cheater? I would prefer someone to share a knowledge rather than be condescending and abusive. Just because you answered first did not mean that I wanted to copy you. I was just jotting down my own answer. And yes it had mistakes. You could have made "suggestions". People react nicely to "suggestions". Just a "suggestion".